# CSV reader and length of CSV, len(list()) not letting me use .next() later

Tags: python, list, csv

So, my overall goal with this was to compare CSV files, but then I ran into this problem.

Here's where the issue is:

```
import csv
csv1 = "C:\\somefile.csv"
file1 = csv.reader(open(csv1))

print len(list(file1))
print file1.next()
```

and for whatever reason, I get a stop iteration error.

Is the len(list(file1)) altering file1 for some reason that I'm just not aware of?
If I put a "print file1" before and after the len(list(file1)), they are both csv reader objects, so it doesn't make much sense to me that .next() wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the `len(list(file1))`. Observe:

```
>>> myiter = (i for i in range(3))
>>> len(list(myiter))
3
>>> myiter.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

And:

```
>>> myiter = (i for i in range(3))
>>> myiter.next()
0
>>> myiter.next()
1
>>> myiter.next()
2
>>> myiter.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

It's not `len()` which is causing the generator to reach the end, but it's the `list()` which turns the generator into a list by taking an item one by one from the iterator, resulting in the generator being exhausted (i.e finished).

To avoid this, simply make a list out of the generator:

```
>>> myiter = (i for i in range(3))
>>> temp = list(myiter)
>>> len(temp)
3
>>> temp
[0, 1, 2]
```

If you ever need it as an iterator again, you can always call `iter()`

Comment: So, what would be the best way to do this if I can't use len(list())??